# objective-c error reassigning variable in if block

Tags: objective-c

I got an error, "Assigning to 'BNRItem' from cincompatible type 'id' ", trying to assign a different object to a variable declared outside of the if block. Why am I not getting the same error when I declared the variable and assign value to it but get an error when I try to reassign it in the if statement? Thanks for your help !

```
BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] getHighValueItems]    <== no error
                  objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if(indexPath.section==1){
        *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] getLowValueItems] <== error 
                 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the * like so...

```
if(indexPath.section==1){
        p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] getLowValueItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

You have already created the pointer above the if, now you are just assigning the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dereferencing operator(*) only while you are declaring the variable for the first time.

```
BNRItem *p = nil;

if(indexPath.section==1){
        p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] getLowValueItems]
                 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

Comment: In a declaration it's not a dereferencing operator, though.